# user login auth in lumen

Tags: php, authentication, lumen-5.2

i tried to do auth as we usually do in laravel5 but it is showing me following error:

> ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 152: Undefined index: provider

after that i tried following link
[Authentication: index not found: provider](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/authentication-index-not-found-provider)

then got following error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard' does not have a method 'attempt'

now i am stuck for this 
So,what should i do for user signin authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Auth middleware on your route make sure to uncomment the appropriate line in your bootstrap/app.php file...

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but still i am getting this error : ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 152: Undefined index: provider

Comment: Do you have an auth config file like? I seem to remember having to creat one like Laravel uses... https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php